# Google Oauth error=invalid_grant, error_description=Bad Request

Tags: google-oauth2

Уже на множестве API различных социальных сетей подключил OAuth, работает хорошо, но в случае с гугловским на этапе получаения токена получаю

```
{"error":"invalid_grant", "error_description":"Bad Request"}
```

хоть то через `get_file_contents` или curl

```
$params_string=http_build_query($params);

        $c = curl_init();


            curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params_string);

        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1',
                                                  'Host: www.googleapis.com',
                                                  'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
```

Код получаю правильный, все параметры прогнал через urlencode, но по неведомой причине получаю такой ответ. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: А разве гугль работает с 1й версией oauth?

Comment: Такого ответа  "error_description":"Bad Request" вообще в природе не существует. Его даже сам гугль найти не может ;)

Comment: В теге указано oauth, а не oauth2, вот я и подумал что 1ая версия.

Comment: Время/дата клиента с гугловским сервером совпадают?

Comment: да, хотя в хедере ответа указано истечение в ту же секунду, что и создание HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Vary: X-Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 03 Aug 2015 12:10:12 GMT
Expires: Mon, 03 Aug 2015 12:10:12 GMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За пару часов удалось определить причину:

...льный, все параметры ***прогнал через urlencode***, но по ..

Вот, именно использование urlencode  было лишним в массиве параметров

```
 $params = array('code' => $_GET['code'],
                            'client_id' => '9ывапршвыалпто.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                            'client_secret' => 'ывлатылвиолыжва',
                            'redirect_uri'=> $domain,
                            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
                                 );
```